# postgresql serial column not resetting

Tags: postgresql

#### UPDATE

Adding `create table` statement to replicate the issue:

`CREATE TABLE table1
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  "timestamp" timestamp with time zone,
  dir integer,
  created timestamp without time zone,
  deleted boolean DEFAULT false,
  CONSTRAINT pk_table1_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
);`

`CREATE TABLE table2
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  "timestamp" timestamp with time zone,
  dir integer,
  created timestamp without time zone,
  deleted boolean DEFAULT false,
  CONSTRAINT pk_table2_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
);`

`insert into table1 (timestamp, dir, created) values('2015-01-01 17:52:00', 3, now()), ('2015-01-02 17:52:00', 1, now()), ('2015-01-03 17:52:00', 1, now());`

`insert into table2
select * from table1`

`insert into table2 (timestamp, dir, created) values('2015-01-04 17:52:00', 3, now());`

ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_table2_id"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.

I am trying to reset the serial counter of a newly created table in postgres using the following:

`SELECT setval('table2_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table2));`

setval returns 3.

But counter is not being set as my next insert statement fails with the following error:

`insert into table2 (timestamp, dir, created) values('2015-01-04 17:52:00', 3, now());`

ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_table2_id"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) already exists.

`select version();`

PostgreSQL 9.4.5 on x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72), 64-bit

Comment: You want `max(id)+1` obviously, but that's not the root of your problem. Please try and post a short reproducible test-case. I don't think you'll be able to. Then, see how your test case differs from your real case and you should see what the problem is.

Comment: Show us the `create table` statement for the table

Comment: After replicating the issue, there doesn't seem to be any problem now on my localhost, but `insert` was failing in the server. Any ideas what could have been the issue? Not possible for me to replicate this issue on server now.